# Google Spreadsheet, Creating multiple rows on form submit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

I have a google form that writes to a spreadsheet.

Currently on form sumbmit a single new row is created.

What I would like to do is;
Have a number field on the form which the user selects a value N.
When the form is submitted I would like the spreadsheet to create N rows of identical data.

I have thought about it in several ways.
What would be best if it could be automated based on N.
Alternatively the value N could be placed in a hidden column H and a script on the spreadsheet could read this and copy the row N times, possibly counting down in column H {N, N-1,...1} if this makes it easier.

Comment: I have to use google-docs because this is a legacy system.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  I was hoping this could be done via the form.  I will add the tag after I propose a possible code solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the form submits a script;

- reads the new data
- gets the number or required rows (N)
- copies a template row to give N blank rows with the correct
  formatting and functions
- copies the new data into place in the new blank rows.

  function onSubmit() {
    //  Sheet to which form submits
    var sheet      = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FORM TARGET 1");
    var lastRow    = sheet.getLastRow();
    // READ THE NUMBER OF NEW ROWS FROM THE DESIGNATED COLUMN IN "FORM TARGET 1"
    var N          = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();

  //  Sheet to which we will write
    var sheetRec   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Target");
    var lastColumn = sheetRec.getLastColumn();
    var lastRowT   = sheetRec.getLastRow();

  // Create N new Rows by copying in the template row N times
    var Template = sheetRec.getRange(2, 1, 1, lastColumn);
    for (j = 1; j <=N; j++) {
      Template.copyTo(sheetRec.getRange(lastRowT + j, 1));
    }

  // Copy new data values into the rows
    var Val1 = sheet.getRange(row, 1);
    var Val2 = sheet.getRange(row, 5);
    var Val3 = sheet.getRange(row, 7);
    var Val4 = sheet.getRange(row, 8);
    Val1.copyValuesToRange(sheetRec, 1, 1, lastRowT + 1, lastRowT + N);
    Val2.copyValuesToRange(sheetRec, 2, 2, lastRowT + 1, lastRowT + N);
    Val3.copyValuesToRange(sheetRec, 4, 4, lastRowT + 1, lastRowT + N);
    Val4.copyValuesToRange(sheetRec, 5, 5, lastRowT + 1, lastRowT + N);
  }

There is a reason I am only copying certain cells from FORM TARGET 1 and why the range cannot be sequential.

I have to use a for loop to copy the template row because copyValuesToRange() & copyFormatsToRange() do not copy functions.  I have functions in some columns that act on the copied data.

I have discussed this issue more completely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265080/google-spreadsheets-script-copyto-vs-copyvaluestoranges-copyformatstoranges).