# Google script for sheets not copying formulas inside cells, only the values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found this excellent script by [--Hyde](https://support.google.com/docs/profile/6471) on [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/) called [moveRowsFromSpreadsheetToSpreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/26537721?msgid=26621631), which enables the transfer of Google Sheet rows between a target sheet and a destination sheet, based on a value set in a dropdown cell for each row in the target sheet.

The challenge i'm facing is that the script is copying & pasting **values only** for each cell, **not the formulas inside those cells**.

My spreadsheet contains cells with `=IMAGE()` formulas and `=HYPERLINK()` formulas and these cells are transferred either empty (in cells where I have `=IMAGE()` formulas) or non-hyperlinked values only (in cells where I have `=HYPERLINK()` formulas).

My hope is, if at all possible, to find a way to modulate the script so it will **copy & paste the rows as they are, with formulas and all**, and not just values only for each cell. Similar to the manual copying & pasting of cell ranges.

I'm guessing it has to do with the `targetRange.setValues([values]);` class in line 269 which probably should have used the `targetRange.copyTo(destination, options);` class. I tried to change the class but it returned the following error: "The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.copyTo. Code line 270"

Here is the script:

```
try {
  // START Modifiable parameters
  var sheetsToWatch =       ['Incoming'];
  var columnsToWatch =      ['Review'];
  var valuesToWatch =       ['ignore','threat','defamatory'];
  var targetSheets =        ['Ignored','Threats','Defamation'];
  var targetSpreadheets =   ['18Cj0oSroQJ_c_4exPK03ubqUd3Fpr8o1M1lzebsyD9g','18Cj0oSroQJ_c_4exPK03ubqUd3Fpr8o1M1lzebsyD9g','18Cj0oSroQJ_c_4exPK03ubqUd3Fpr8o1M1lzebsyD9g'];
  var targetIdColumn =      ['Review'];
  var targetValues =        [];
  var copyInsteadOfMove =   [false, false, false];
  var numColumnsToMove =    [];
  var changeColumnOrderTo = [];
  var sheetsToSort =        [];
  var columnToSortBy =      [];
  var sortAscending =       [];
  // END modifiable parameters
} catch (error) {
  showAndThrow_(error);
}

function moveRowsFromSpreadsheetToSpreadsheet_(e) {
  if (!e || !e.range) {
    return;
  }
  var sourceSheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var sourceSheetName = sourceSheet.getName();
  if (sheetsToWatch.indexOf(sourceSheetName) === -1) {
    return;
  }
  var columnLabelRow = sourceSheet.getFrozenRows() || 1;
  var numSheetColumns = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();
  var columnLabels = sourceSheet.getRange(columnLabelRow, 1, 1, numSheetColumns).getValues()[0];
  if (targetIdColumn.length && targetValues.length) {
    var targetIdColumnNumber = columnLabels.indexOf(targetIdColumn[0]) + 1;
    if (!targetIdColumnNumber) {
      throw new Error('Could not find a column named "' + String(targetIdColumn[0]) + '".');
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0, numValuesToWatch = valuesToWatch.length; i < numValuesToWatch; i++) {
    valuesToWatch[i] = String(valuesToWatch[i]).toLowerCase();
  }
  var values = e.range.getDisplayValues();
  var rowsToDelete = [];
  var numRowsMoved = 0;
  var messageOnDisplay = false;
  for (var row = 0, numRows = values.length; row < numRows; row++) {
    for (var column = 0, numColumns = values[row].length; column < numColumns; column++) {
      if (e.range.rowStart + row <= columnLabelRow) {
        continue;
      }
      var columnLabel = columnLabels[e.range.columnStart - 1 + column];
      if (columnsToWatch.indexOf(columnLabel) === -1) {
        continue;
      }
      var valueLowerCase = values[row][column].toLowerCase();
      var valuesToWatchIndex = valuesToWatch.indexOf(valueLowerCase);
      if (valuesToWatchIndex === -1) {
        continue;
      }
      if (targetIdColumn.length && targetValues.length) {
        var valueInTargetIdColumn = sourceSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart + row, targetIdColumnNumber).getValue();
        var targetIndex = targetValues.indexOf(valueInTargetIdColumn);
      } else {
        targetIndex = valuesToWatchIndex;
      }  
      if (targetIndex === -1) {
        continue;
      }
      // all checks done, there is at least one row to move
      var movedRowIndex = e.range.rowStart + row;
      if (!messageOnDisplay) {
        showMessage_('Moving rows...', 30);
        messageOnDisplay = true;
      }
      var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart + row, 1, 1, numSheetColumns);
      var rowValuesInOriginalOrder = sourceRange.getValues()[0];
      if (numColumnsToMove[targetIndex] !== undefined) {
        var rowValues = rowValuesInOriginalOrder.slice(0, numColumnsToMove[targetIndex]);
      } else {
        rowValues = rowValuesInOriginalOrder.slice();
      }
      for (var changeIndex = 0; changeIndex < changeColumnOrderTo.length; changeIndex++) {
        if (changeColumnOrderTo[changeIndex] !== undefined) {
          rowValues[changeIndex] = rowValuesInOriginalOrder[changeColumnOrderTo[changeIndex]];
        } else if (rowValues[changeIndex] === undefined) {
          rowValues[changeIndex] = null;
        }
      }
      if (targetSpreadheets[targetIndex]) {
        try {
          var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadheets[targetIndex]);
        } catch (error) {
          var ssIdShortened = String(targetSpreadheets[targetIndex]).slice(0, 5) + '...' + String(targetSpreadheets[targetIndex]).slice(-5);
          throw new Error("Could not find the target spreadsheet with ID '" + ssIdShortened + "'.");
        }
      } else {
        targetSpreadsheet = sourceSheet.getParent();
      }
      var targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetSheets[targetIndex]);
      if (!targetSheet) {
        throw new Error("Could not find the target sheet '" + targetSheets[targetIndex] + "'.");
      }
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, rowValues.length);
      targetRange.setValues([rowValues]);
      numRowsMoved += 1;
      if (!copyInsteadOfMove[targetIndex]) {
        rowsToDelete.push(e.range.rowStart + row);
      }
    } // column
  } // row
  if (messageOnDisplay) {
    var message = (rowsToDelete.length ? 'Moved ' : 'Copied ') + numRowsMoved + (numRowsMoved === 1 ? ' row.' : ' rows.');
    showMessage_('Moving rows... done. ' + message);
  }
  if (rowsToDelete.length) {
    for (var i = rowsToDelete.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      sourceSheet.deleteRow(rowsToDelete[i]);
    }
  }
  return { sourceSheet: sourceSheet, targetSheet: targetSheet };
}

function installOnEditTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('moveRowsAndSortSheet_')
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
  .onEdit()
  .create();  
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with the `targetRange.setValues([values]);` class in line 269 which probably should have used the `targetRange.copyTo(destination, options);` class. I tried to change the class but it returned an error :-(

Comment: Add your comment to the question including the textual error that you got. Also intead of adding the whole code make a [mcve]

Comment: Hi Rubén, I followed your instructions, added the error message and cleaned the code provided. Thank you...

Comment: I think @Rubén answers pretty much solves your problem, anyway, in case you are having doubt you can search a little bit more about `copyTo` to find more questions in stack relevant to your case:
[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864831/copyto-using-contentsonlytrue-not-working) and 
[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265080/google-spreadsheets-script-copyto-vs-copyvaluestoranges-copyformatstoranges)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question

> I tried to change the class but it returned the following error: "The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.copyTo. Code line 270"

The error means that the first argument is an Array of numbers but `SpreadsheetApp.Range.copyTo` requires a Class Range object.

The solution to this error is to pass an appropiate object. By the other hand, the `copyTo` method should be applied to the source range instead of the target range.

Instead of

```
targetRange.copyTo(destination, options);
```

try

```
sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, options);
```